# how to add space between two text in alert dialog

Tags: android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to add a space between two text in alertdialog.

[image]

how can I add a space between text ".....27 Speed" and "2. Merek"?
can anybody help me with this issue. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean a new line then `\n`

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean a newline. It can be added using `"\n"` .

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` for a line break and `\t` if you want to insert a tab.

You can also use some XML tags for basic formatting:  for bold text,  for italics, and  for underlined text.

Other formatting options are shown in this article on the Android Developers' site: [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)